# how to make hover state div relative to an individual <li> and not the <li> container?

Tags: css, hover, position

i have several `<li>`'s that have the `display: inline` property so that they are lined up next to each other.

these `<li>`'s contains images so the effect is lots of thumbnail size images beside each other.

upon hovering on the image i have set a css property that displays the contents of a hidden div.

this div is styled and appears above the image and offset left 50px and top -200px (think tooltip style positioning and display).

```
#information {
    display: none;
}

ul li:hover #information {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    width: 190px;
    height: 250px;
    left: 50px;
    top: -200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

the behaviour that i want is that the hover state div offset is relative to the image ie the individual `<li>`.

the behaviour i currently have is that the hover state div offset is relative to the container for all the `<li>`'s.

in the above code sample, you can see that the hover state div position is absolute, i did have the position set to relative, but when hovering this caused the other `<li>`'s to change their position (this is possibly because the hover state div must have a `display: block` property to change the original `display: hidden` property) and the hover state div was still being displayed relative to the container and not the individual `<li>`.  when i set the position to absolute, the `<li>`'s retain their positioning.

so my question is how do i make the hover state div's offset relative to the individual `<li>` and not the container for the `<li>`'s.

Answer (score 1):

the solution was to add a `position: relative` to the ul li and a z-index of 2 to the hover state div.

Comment: this ended up being problematic in that the hover state div was beneath other elements - this is a problem that i am troubleshooting now and will post solution when it has been found.